# How to search for query on user's wall in Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to find all user's posts that matches to my pattern.
Assume I have all permissions I need.

I tried
https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?q=query&limit=10
but in response I get only 1-3 matches (on the next page of results there are another 1-3 matches etc.)

What can I do to get e.g. 10 of them per page?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this nice blog about how the items can get "lost" when requesting 10 and then only getting 3

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Facebook uses a very poor implementation here.

> You might notice that the number of results returned is not always equal to the “limit” specified. This is expected behavior.

It's kinda crazy how they actually write a blog article on how poor their pagination/filtering really is.  Kinda like their proud of it or something.  Definitely nothing to be proud of here.  Lol, "this is expected behavior"?!?

And I also love this line.

> This can make paging difficult and confusing.

Facebook's saying: **Let us not only be proud of our crappy design but also then rub it in the users' noses!!**

In my opinion, Facebook should query all results (even more than the limit says), determine what can be shown to the user, and filter the results, and THEN start pagination and limits on that.

Facebook, hear my cry, **hire or rent some talented database engineers to come in and help you solve this huge problem**.  Also *stop posting blog articles like you're proud of the fact that it's messed up*.

Comment: Well, I've this post, but I have all permissions to access the posts I request.

Comment: Facebook admits to paginating poorly and shows you how incorrect their logic is. And yet you still wonder why your pagination results are not what you expect. Stop wondering and accept the fact that what Facebook gives you for pagination is not going to be what you expect.